# How to create a layer switcher in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I had used the following layers in leaflet,now i want to switch between the 4 layers ,please tell the code to create a layer switcher control in leaflet

```
// night layer
//var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/a7db5562d0cd4fe0a2d8983fbb3b5519/999/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',


//golden layer
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/a7db5562d0cd4fe0a2d8983fbb3b5519/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

//black layer
//var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',

osmAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2012 <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttribution});
```

Comment: How you read the tutorial?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! You might want's to read this Leaflet tutorial http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html
It addresses pretty much what you need. Please read the docs before asking a question next time.

Comment: R.K. you're right. I just hate saying "Read the Docs" sometimes

Comment: @geomajor56 Yeah. I hate doing it too but this one's featured prominently in the docs. I just wish the OP went through the tutorial before asking. It's rather brief. A little effort goes a long way.

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll need to rename your basemaps differently:

```
// night layer
var night = http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/a7db5562d0cd4fe0a2d8983fbb3b5519/999/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',

//golden layer
var golden = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/a7db5562d0cd4fe0a2d8983fbb3b5519/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

//black layer
var black = 'http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
```

Then use the Layer Control option as shown in this [Leaflet Example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/).

I haven't tried [this](https://github.com/vogdb/SelectLayersControl) plugin, but it's a different type of control for selecting layers.

Hope this gets you started.